# MySQL Left Join help

Tags: mysql, join

Hello again community,

I posted a question just over an hour ago asking for some help fixing a SQL query, that was promptly answered and was a great help. Sadly though, upon reflection and further usage, it turns out that the query was returning all rows in the targeted table. I validated this by putting the mysql_fetch_object inside a while loop.

So what I desperately need now is someone to have a look at the SQL query and tell me what is going wrong and if possible how to fix it. I simply just need one row (the correct row) to be found when using $_SESSION['model'] as the reference.

Below is the full content of my previous question.

Thank you in advance.

============================================================================

web_quote_models table

```
id | model       | product_id | cpu_id | ram_id | hdd_id | os_id | opt_id
=========================================================================
1  | 000001      | 1          | 1      | 1      | 1      | 1     | 1
2  | 000002      | 1          | 2      | 2      | 2      | 2     | 2
3  | 000003      | 1          | 3      | 3      | 3      | 3     | 3
4  | 000004      | 1          | 4      | 4      | 4      | 4     | 4
```

web_quote_component_cpu table

```
id | name
==========================================================================
1  | Intel&reg; Core&trade; i3 2100 3.1GHz dual-core
2  | Intel&reg; Core&trade; i5 2500 2.7GHz quad-core
3  | Intel&reg; Core%trade; i7 2600 3.4GHz 8mb Cache dual-core
```

So what I need to achieve is a query that will look inside the web_quote_models table and match the model field with a $_SESSION['model'] then match the web_quote_models.cpu_id field with the web_quote_component.id.

This is what I have so far; I cant be too far off I think.

```
("
 SELECT web_quote_component_cpu.name
 FROM web_quote_component_cpu
 LEFT JOIN web_quote_models
 ON web_quote_component_cpu.id=web_quote_models.cpu_id
 AND web_quote_models.name='".$_SESSION['model']."'
");
```

A massive thank you in advance to anyone that helps.

Dan.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: AND web_quote_models. **model** ='".$_SESSION['model']."'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Left Join`, you get entries from the table on the left side of `join` (that is `web_quote_component_cpu`) even if they are not matched with the other table. If you want entries that only match, use `join` instead of `left join`.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Thank you, Just tried taking out `LEFT` and that worked a charm, that makes perfect sense also, thank you for the explanation also; it certainly helped me understand the command better.

Comment: No problem. Just for future reference, simple `join` is called `inner join`. You also have `outer join`s that work like I mentioned. That is `left outer join` or simply `left join` includes all from left table even if not matched. `right join` does the same with the right table and `outer join` does from both tables.

Comment: Greatly appreciated explanation bud.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT web_quote_component_cpu.name FROM web_quote_component_cpu JOIN web_quote_models ON web_quote_component_cpu.id = web_quote_models.cpu_id WHERE web_quote_models.model = $_SESSION['model]

(or something like that)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and to show the exact query that will do the job.

Comment: No bother, MySQL join statements are probably one of the most fiddly but useful aspects of it. The accepted answer goes into detail on the differences but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 has a load of info on the different types and effects.

Comment: Thank you the link, also very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT web_quote_component_cpu.name
   FROM web_quote_component_cpu
   LEFT JOIN web_quote_models ON web_quote_component_cpu.id=web_quote_models.cpu_id
   WHERE web_quote_models.name='".$_SESSION['model']."' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sadly as mentioned in the other responses, using LEFT JOIN will get all the rows from the web_quote_component_cpu table regardless of the value of $_SESSION['model'] thus limiting the callback to 1 would just call back the first row only. Well that's what I have ascertained anyhow.